# Method to minimize a quadratic form

Tags: matlab, optimization, quadratic-form

How should I minimize a quadratic form $g(x)^TA(x)^{-1}g(x)$ with respect to $x$, where $g$ is a vector which depends on the vector $x$? This quadratic form is obtained from a quasi likelihood equation. I use Matlab.

Edit: I will provide more details. The variable is the column vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{dim}.$  We define $g_i=( U_i^t(Y_i-U_i x);
        U_i'M_i(Y_i-U_ix)) \in \mathbb{R}^{2dim \times 1}$  (the notation ';' denotes vertical concatenation) for $i=1,\ldots,n.$ Define $g=1/n \sum_i g_i$ and let $A(x)=1/n\sum_i g_i g_i^t$. Minimize $$g^t A^{-1} g$$. $g_i$ is a real vector which clearly depends on the unknown $x$, and $A$ is the sample covariance matrix of $g_1,\ldots,g_n$. $U_i, M_i$ are matrices which do not depend on x, $Y_i$ denote **column** vectors who do not depend on the column vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{dim}.$

The definitions come from a statistical model $Y_i=U_i x+\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{N_i \times 1}$, where $U_i \in \mathbb{R}^{N_i \times dim}$ where $U_i$ and $Y_i$ are treated as constant (because we want to determine the parameter vector $x$)

Comment: As a function of $\beta$ this will usually *not* be a quadratic form. Since you don't tell us how $v$ and $A$ depend on $\beta$, you are basically asking how to minimize almost *any* function of any vector. Obviously that's too broad to handle, but perhaps you could edit this question to narrow it down to something answerable?

Comment: I appreciate the effort to add detail. The problem now is that it has no direct or obvious connection with the original question. In terms of $g_i$, $U_i$, $M_i$, $Y_i$, what is $v$? What is $\beta$?

Comment: Excuse me, edited.

Comment: Thank you--I think you're almost there. However, some clarification about the dimensions may be needed. It appears that $g_i$ is a *matrix* (because it is the "vertical concatenation" of "vectors"), whence $f=g^\prime A^{-1} g$ is also a matrix. It makes no sense to minimize a matrix. Please also consider what it might mean to claim that "$g_i$ is ... multivariate variable": exactly which of the symbols from which it is defined are random variables? And if the $g_i$ are random, then so is $f$, so in what sense could it be "minimized"?

Comment: $g_i$ are not stochastic, because we suppose $Y_i,U_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ are given.

Comment: Your latest comment flatly contradicts the part of your post that states "...  $g_i$ is considered multivariate variable with mean $0$, ... ." It does not address the more fundamental issue that $f$ appears to be a matrix and not a scalar. Could you edit the post to fix these problems?

Comment: Ok, but how can $f$ be a matrix if I vertically concatenate two column vectors?

Comment: This is FAR from a quadratic form of any easy representation. The inverse makes it so complicated. You can use some global minimizer, like genetic algorithm, simulated annealer, evolutionary algorithm, etc. Then use a local minimizer, say, Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm to fine tune the result.

Comment: I agree with Hans on the A matrix. If A is not symmetric at least, that could be anything. But on the suggestion i cannot disagree more. GA, SA, EAs methods are eligible only when lacking of any numerical structure -i.e. they are the Brute Force methods available around there-.

Comment: As-is, from the nested summations, the nexted x variable and the inverse matrix, i would not spend too much time on an specific algebraic approach for the minimization. As Hans said, some Non-linear Optimization method would be a good trial. But i am not clear about any trick or caveat making this problem into a simpler one. Maybe solving the likelihood, or imposing a model in another fashion could be a better solution...